# How to remove [setupvars.sh] OpenVINO

Tags: software-installation

While I installed Intel Neural Compute Stick 2，I encountered some problems and could not run applications. So I intend to remove OpenVINO and then re-install the system again.

1. Ubuntu Terminal shows:

   ```
   [setupvars.sh] OpenVINO environment initialized
   ```
2. Path

   ```
   /opt/intel/openvivo_2019.1.144/openvino_toolkit_uninstaller/uninstall
   ```

After I checked either Intel forum and Google, I could not find any answers.

Please inform me what's the command to remove OpenVINO.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to comment out this line in your `~/.bashrc`

`source ~/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh`
then close and reopen your terminal and

`[setupvars.sh] OpenVINO environment initialized` should be gone

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

While I tried the command

```
sudo opt/intel/openvino_2019.1.144/openvino_toolkit_uninstaller/uninstall_GUI.sh
```

`[setupvars.sh] OpenVINO environment initialized` disappeared.

However, the ubuntu terminal has the following popup each time when I open the terminal.

```
bash: /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh: No such file or directory ​​​​
```

I use the following to solve the problem:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and then delete `intel openvino` code and save the `.bashrc` file.

After that, the Ubuntu terminal goes back to normal.